# Fastest way to concatenate two numbers in Python

Tags: python, atoi

suppose you have two strings (with digits only) in Python, say string a and string b. What is the fastest way to produce the number c = a.b (hence, a integer part, and b decimal part)?

Comment: Closing as not constructive. I *would* humor it if there was prior research done (actually a -1 because no prior effort is shown), such as benchmarks of various approaches *you know about*.

Comment: @pst: My +1.  There are no stupid questions.  This one is definitely not.  You do not know the motivation behind.  And the answers prove that the fastest solution was not considered at first.  There is a valuable discussion.

Comment: @pepr Supposing there are no "stupid questions" there are still "non-researched questions" and they generally make for very shallow "discussions" because a base has *not* been established. This is one. Again, I *would* humor it if there *was* previous work/research done (and shown).

Comment: May I ask: why are you interested in the fastest way of achieving this?

Answer (score 4):

If quicker is meant in terms of speed, my usage recommends me this:

```
float("%s.%s"% ("12", "345"))
```

timeit results:

```
>>> timeit.Timer('float("%s.%s"% ("12", "245"))').timeit()
0.39421987533569336

>>> timeit.Timer('float("{0}.{1}".format("12", "245"))').timeit()
0.573634147644043
```

Comment: Just curious, are you using Python 2.x or 3.x?

Comment: 2.7.1 on a mac. And to add, using assignments beforehand slows things down a bit but the there is still penalty for the format.

Answer (score 3):

Primitive formatting (might be the quickest? ): `float(str(a) + '.' + str(b))`

This solution doesn't need to parse a format string.

[Added as the answer to the disbelievers]

```
>>> timeit.Timer('float("%s.%s"% ("12", "245"))').timeit()
1.147318164738806
>>> timeit.Timer('float("{0}.{1}".format("12", "245"))').timeit()
1.5033958226534452
>>> timeit.Timer('float("12" + "." + "245")').timeit()
0.6646503955111598
```

Part of the explanation could be that you can always write `%s` even for the int arguments.  It is likely that there is an extra string conversion when formatted via % or via `.format()`.

Comment: Using `+` creates extra objects which are thrown away since strings are immutable.

Comment: The alternatives don't do that?

Comment: Using string formatting wouldn't. In your example, you make a new str for a and b, then a new str for a + '.', then that + b

Comment: @Daenyth what if you don't use `str(a)` and `str(b)`? Use instead `a` and `b` and you (probably) won't have this problem. Plus, OP says a and b are strings, so no need to use `str`..

Comment: @Daenyth While that's true, it can still be faster than formatting when you have only a few short strings

Comment: I have added the timeit.  Yes, it is about two times faster :)  This is my winner!

Comment: @jadkik94 - yes, I missed it. It's ``float(a + '.' + b)``

Comment: @Daenyth The number of "extra objects" does not matter. Only the final result -- in terms of "benchmarked numbers" -- matters.

Comment: You're right. I should have benchmarked before assuming.

Answer (score 1):

Using `float` and `format`.

```
>>> a, b = '12', '345'
>>> float('{0}.{1}'.format(a, b))
12.345
```

EDIT: Cannot claim this is fastest (as I haven't tested the speed w.r.t. other solutions), but does get the job done.

Comment: This is most definitely not the fastest for short strings, though it may be the best. Old-style formatting is faster (at least for versions of Python I've used) than new-style formatting, and just adding strings can be faster if they're short, you don't need the capabilities of string formatting, and there aren't very many strings.

Comment: @agf Interesting. I did not know that old style formatting was faster in 2.x. Out of curiosity, have you tried comparing the speeds in 3.x? (I haven't)

Comment: I believe it is still slower in 3.2 but I can't test right now.

Answer (score 0):

This will raise a `ValueError` if `a` or `b` cannot be converted to integers (if not only digits for example):

```
float('%d.%d' % (int(a), int(b)))
```

(tested on Python 2.7)